# How to serve user-uploaded files on Swisscom Application Cloud?

Tags: cloud-foundry, object-storage, swisscomdev

As applications shouldn't write files to the local file system it makes sense to store user-uploaded files in the [Dynamic Storage](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/dynamic.html) provided by Swisscom.

The Dynamic Storage service is similar to Amazon S3 where you would usually make the bucket with the user-uploaded files publicly readable with a [bucket policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2).

However how would I serve user-uploaded files from the Dynamic Storage as the "Put Bucket policy" is an [unsupported operation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/dynamic.html#unsupported)?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, dynamic storage of Swisscom does not support the „PUT bucket policy“ operation. But you can serve files directly to the user by generating pre-signed URLs.

See [Share an Object with Others](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

> All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has
>   permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can
>   optionally share objects with others by creating a pre-signed URL,
>   using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission
>   to download the objects.
>
> When you create a pre-signed URL for your object, you must provide
>   your security credentials, specify a bucket name, an object key,
>   specify the HTTP method (GET to download the object) and expiration
>   date and time. The pre-signed URLs are valid only for the specified
>   duration.
>
> Anyone who receives the pre-signed URL can then access the object. For
>   example, if you have a video in your bucket and both the bucket and
>   the object are private, you can share the video with others by
>   generating a pre-signed URL.

By using a pre-signed URL you have to define how long the URL shall be valid. We recommend to choose an expiration date that makes sense for the specific use-case.

Info: currently the S3 storage is powered by [Atmos](http://www.celerra.me/storage/atmos/atmos.htm)