# S3 ACL Public-Read on Swisscom Cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

AFAIK Swisscom does not support Uploads into the S3 Service with a public-read status. The only way to share a file is via presigned url. Is this correct? Already asked here:

[How to serve user-uploaded files on Swisscom Application Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332923/how-to-serve-user-uploaded-files-on-swisscom-application-cloud)

In the docs, it's written though that `PUT Object ACL`is [supported](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/dynamic.html#supported). According to the [Amazon Specs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html) this should include `public-read` as well.

What is the current case now? What is the best workaround if it's not possible to store public readable binaries? For example to serve images for a website stored on Swisscom S3?

Comment: "*into the S3 Service*" ... I assume you are not referring to genuine Amazon S3 but rather an S3 compatible service. Is that correct?  Have you tried settting `x-amz-acl: public-read` in the headers when uploading a file there?

Comment: I mean explicitly the S3 Service of swisscom...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swisscom Dynamic Storage currently does not support static web pages, which means every http request has to be signed. Workaround are shareable URLs with a very long expiration date so called Pre-signed Object URL.

Comment: Would be great to have that feature though – Swisscom is probably the only S3 provider which has a transparent payment policy and includes traffic costs in a monthly flat rate. A perfect solution to host public accessible data for small startups. 

I think it would also be nice to have a non-us / non-amazon company offering competitive cloud products based in Switzerland. It's a «service public» of the future thing. Static Websites can be a reason to still stay with Amazon's S3.

Comment: Hey @rokfor. Please describe your S3 use case. Maybe you can use https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack "Deploy static HTML/JS/CSS apps to Cloud Foundry" as a workaround? We are working on making the S3 support better.

Comment: I'm running a cloud based, headless cms and I use s3 as storage backend for the uploaded binary files. amazon offers the option to change the status to «public readable» for uploaded files, which makes it a perfect solution to store the data.